# How to include a custom root node in json response for Service Stack?

Tags: servicestack

How might one add a custom root node to the response of a service stack operation?

**{"users":**
   [{"id":1,"username":"qt5p0a5ilm","name":"Clifford"

Update: This is how I've setup the request dto

```
[Route("/property", "GET")]
public class AllProperties : IReturn<List<Property>> 
{

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the Response DTO to match the desired shape of the JSON you wish to return. e.g:

```
public class UsersResponse
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```